# Google Directory Service query with space and wildcard: behavior not matching expectations

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-directory-api

I ran into some unexpected behavior when trying to combine whitespaces in a Directory Service API search query with a wildcard character:

### Code

```
Directory ds =  new GoogleDirectoryServiceManager().getDirectoryService("admin@randomdomain.com");
Directory.Users usersClient = ds.users();

String lastNameBuffer = term;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if(term.contains(" ")){        
    sb.append("\'");
    sb.append(lastNameBuffer);
    sb.append("*\'");
}else{
    sb.append(lastNameBuffer);
    sb.append("*");
}

queryString = "familyName:" + sb.toString();
users = usersClient.list()
                .setDomain("randomdomain.com")
                .setQuery(queryString)
                .setMaxResults(MAX_DIRECTORY_RESULTS)
                .setFields("users(name,primaryEmail,thumbnailPhotoUrl)")
                .execute();
```

I added the single quotes to search through the directory with the spaces. Following is an extract from the [Google Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users#values):

> Surround with single quotes ' if the query contains whitespace. Escape single quotes in queries with \', for example 'Valentine\'s Day'.

### Input

1. "johns" --> Returns all users with Johnson name (`familyName: johns*`) **GOOD**
2. "van bur" --> Does not return any users (`familyName: 'van bur*'`) **NOT GOOD**
3. "van buren" --> Returns all users with Van Buren name (`familyName: 'van buren*'`) **GOOD**

### tl;dr

Is it not possible to combine a search query with spaces with a wildcard? Or does the wildcard symbol (`*`) have to be escaped?
What query do I need to use to successfully return a list of users in case #2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During my attempts with [the API explorer embedded in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list), I have noted that the following query, **the same as you without the single quotes**, would work as expected on my test domain. Can you test it ?

```
familyName:van bur
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! That's it. Even the wildcard character is not required. I still need to add it for last names without spaces, but this works like a charm! Thanks a lot!